# Angry state of my father

Tags: meaning

> Angry state of my father is very terrifying.
>
> When my father is angry He is very terrifying.

Does these sentence have nearly same meaning . I mean if I say the first sentence instead of the second one would hearer can understand me very well?

Comment: Your first version is syntactically invalid unless you precede it by the definite article (**The** angry state...)*, but even then it's not at all idiomatic. The second version is fine, but if you specifically want to include the word ***state***, consider *My father in his/an angry state is terrifying*. BTW - "terrifying" doesn't take "gradeable intensifiers" very well, only "end-of-the-spectrum" qualifiers - so you can be ***completely*** or ***totally** terrified*, but it's unusual to be ***rather, a bit,*** or ***very** terrified*

Comment: (Being terrified is a bit like being pregnant; no half-measures - you either are or you aren't! :)

Comment: Please fix your punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

The first is odd, but not incorrect.  Simply in colloquial speech we don't talk about emotions in terms of "The angry state ..."

The second is good, except the pronoun "he" shouldn't have a capital letter.  I would also not use "very terrifying" (since terrifying already *very*)

Answer (score -1):

Either sentence would be well enough understood, but either would also be quickly recognized as produced by a non-native speaker.

One way to say it more naturally is, "When my father is angry, it's terrifying." Here, you **could** say *my* instead of *it's*, but the "m" is lower case. Note too that there aren't degrees of terrifying, so no *very*.

Comment: I do not agree that "When my father is angry, he's terrifying" is less idiomatic than "When my father is angry, it's terrifying." In fact, "he's" seems to me more natural than "it's." I suspect that you are reacting to the odd punctuation and capitalization rather than the actual wording. Perhaps consider editing?